# How to use novaexchange API

Tags: api

I am trying to get all their BTC market by accessing

Reply with quote Edit message Delete message  #1
https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/markets/BTC

It doesn't work.

I read their API documentation try to find samples on web and I can't find it

https://novaexchange.com/remote/faq/

The format is this

/remote/v2/markets/

Neither

https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/markets/BTC

nor

https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/markets/btc

works

So I wonder what's work. I look around on google and can't find a sample of URL that works.

Answer (score 2):

I have play with this api in particular many times, the call that always works that is similar of the one you are trying is https://novaexchange.com/remote/v2/markets/ from there you have to filter the pairs for just getting BTC pairs.